# Why should I go through the purchasing process to install a product priced $0.00?

Tags: software-center, usability

In Software Center, I have to run through the purchasing process even if a product is priced with 0$ (e.g. 'Full Circle Magazine'). That makes no sense to me. If the price of the product is 'zero', It should not lead through the purchasing process and instead should just let me install the product straightaway.

Can I know why this is the case and can someone point me to the design decisions for this if there are any?

Comment: This question has been reopened.  Discussion of the merits of this question should be via this meta question, not by comments or flags.  Thank-you.  http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3075/are-questions-about-design-decisions-considered-constructive

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, free software end up in software-center through Debian repository import but there are special channels to get software directly into Ubuntu repository.

The reason why some products end up with a price tag of $0.00 but have to be installed through a purchasing process is because they were added directly to the Ubuntu repository through the myapps.ubuntu.com portal. Because of the interface of the portal, the only way to release the product for free is if you set a $0.00 price. Hence, you see a buy button for products even when you don't actually have to pay anything for the product.

This issue has been notified and the [design spec](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter?action=diff&rev2=623&rev1=622) of software-center has been modified to sort this issue.

A [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/968974) has already been filed to rectify this problem and hopefully the Q-release will have this bug fixed.

Comment: Great answer. Is there any update I'm missing or is the issue persisting for everyone?

Comment: If you see the linked bug report, you would notice the issue is yet to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I joined my "vote" to the issue you linked, I leared a lot in the way thanks to you, regards!